# JSHint and issue with underscore '_'

Tags: node.js, jshint, lodash

Getting the following error when running jshint;

```
line 4   col 5  Redefinition of '_'.
```

the code is complaining out is;

```
var _ = require('lodash');
```

jshint in project

```
{
    "node": true,
    "esnext": true,
    "bitwise": true,
    "eqeqeq": true,
    "immed": true,
    "latedef": "nofunc",
    "newcap": true,
    "noarg": true,
    "regexp": true,
    "undef": true,
    "smarttabs": true,
    "asi": true,
    "debug": true,
    "globals": {
        "angular": false,
        "_": false
    }
}
```

Comment: `Redefinition` suggests you have already defined it somewhere

Comment: are you sure that jshint config file is being parsed?
Try adding "someglobal" : true to the globals, and then do var someglobal = 123;
Does it raise an exception for redefining someglobal?

Answer (score 3):

Updated the .jshintrc to the following which seems to have resolved the problem.

```
{
    "node": true,
    "browser": true,
    "esnext": true,
    "bitwise": false,
    "camelcase": false,
    "eqeqeq": true,
    "immed": true,
    "indent": 4,
    "latedef": true,
    "newcap": true,
    "noarg": true,
    "quotmark": "single",
    "regexp": true,
    "undef": true,
    "unused": false,    
    "strict": true,
    "trailing": true,
    "smarttabs": true,
    "globals": {
        "jQuery": true,
        "angular": true,
        "console": true,
        "AppConfig": true,
        "$": true,
        "_": true,
        "moment": true,
        "module": true,
        "inject": true,
        "browser": true,
        "element": true,

        "describe": true,
        "before": true,
        "beforeEach": true,
        "after": true,
        "afterEach": true,
        "expect": true,
        "it": true,
        "by": true,
        "chai": true
    }
}
```

Also created a .jshintrc-spec

```
{
  "extends": ".jshintrc",
  "globals": {
    "describe": true,
    "it": true,
    "before": true,
    "beforeEach": true,
    "after": true,
    "afterEach": true,
    "chai": true,
    "inject" : true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A better (and commonly used) way to resolve this is to use double underscores `__` while requiring either `underscore` or the `lodash` library. No need to make a change to the `jshintrc` file just for this.